# Swift UI animation 360 degree spin

Tags: swiftui

Good day,

I have a flag program and am looking to add animation such that when the correct flag is tapped it spins around 360 degrees on the y-axis.

I can write the code and make all 3 flags spin, regardless of whether the correct flag is tapped, by writing the code under "ForEach" but am failing when I try to write the code under the function flagTapped, where the if clause is written that determines if the number == correctAnswer. This is where I felt the code needed to be written. Any help would be much appreciated.  code is below:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State private var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Ireland", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"].shuffled()

@State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)



@State private var showingScore = false // tells us if alert is showing or not

@State private var scoreTitle = "" // title inside the alert

@State private var score = 0



@State private var animationAmount = 0.0



var body: some View {

    ZStack {

        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .black]),

                       startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)

        VStack(spacing: 30) {

            VStack {

                Text("Tap the flag of")

                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                Text(countries[correctAnswer])

                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                    .font(.largeTitle)

                    .fontWeight(.black)

                

            }



            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { number in

                Button(action: {

                    self.flagTapped(number)

                }) {

                    Image(self.countries[number])

                        .renderingMode(.original)

                        .clipShape(Capsule())

                        .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))

                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)

                        

                }

            }

            Spacer()

        }

    }

    .alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {

        Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(score)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {

            self.askQuestion()

        })

    }

}



//======================================



func flagTapped(_ number: Int) {

    if number == correctAnswer {

        scoreTitle = "Correct"

        score += 100

        Button() {

            withAnimation {

                self.animationAmount += 360

            }

        }

        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))

           

        

    } else {

        scoreTitle = "Wrong. This was the flag of \(countries[number])"

        score -= 100

    }

    showingScore = true

    

}



//====================================

func askQuestion() {

    countries.shuffle()

    correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)

}
```

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

```
static var previews: some View {

    ContentView()

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code to make things easier.

```
struct FlagButton: View {
    var country: String
    var onTap: () -> ()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.onTap()
        }) {
            Image(country)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
        } 
    }
}
```

Use it in `ForEach`

```
FlagButton(country: self.countries[number]) {
      flagTapped(number)
}
```

In your code, you are adding a new button inside the Button on tap if the answer is correct. It is wrong in `SwiftUI`. Remove the button from `flagTapped`. You don't need to use it. You just need to rotate it if the answer is correct.

```
    func flagTapped(_ number: Int) {
        if number == correctAnswer {
            scoreTitle = "Correct"
            score += 100
            withAnimation {
                self.animationAmount += 360
            }
        } else {
            scoreTitle = "Wrong. This was the flag of \(countries[number])"
            score -= 100
        }
        showingScore = true
    }
```

Use `rotation3DEffect` modifier on the `FlagButton`.

Rotate if the answer is correct. Otherwise, dont.

```
.degrees(number == correctAnswer ? animationAmount: 0)
```

```
.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(number == correctAnswer ? animationAmount: 0), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
```

All of your code!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Ireland", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"].shuffled()
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    @State private var showingScore = false // tells us if alert is showing or not
    @State private var scoreTitle = "" // title inside the alert
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var animationAmount = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .black]),
                           startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Tap the flag of")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                }
                ForEach(0 ..< 3) { number in
                    FlagButton(country: self.countries[number]) {
                        flagTapped(number)
                    }
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(number == correctAnswer ? animationAmount: 0), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
            Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(score)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                self.askQuestion()
            })
        }
    }
    
    
    func askQuestion() {
        countries.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    }
    
    func flagTapped(_ number: Int) {
        if number == correctAnswer {
            scoreTitle = "Correct"
            score += 100
            withAnimation {
                self.animationAmount += 360
            }
        } else {
            scoreTitle = "Wrong. This was the flag of \(countries[number])"
            score -= 100
        }
        showingScore = true
    }
}

struct FlagButton: View {
    var country: String
    var onTap: () -> ()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.onTap()
        }) {
            Image(country)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
        }
    }
}
```